# How do you dynamically change a directives controller in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, hyperlink, controller, directive

I have my directive and I want to change the controller and html of a small section of the page onclick of a submit button. Changeing the HTML is working but changing the controller is not.

The line: attrs.ngController = "wordlistsPageController";
is not working. Please let me know what I can do to dynamically set the controller since this does not work.

It is a little web app game, so I do not want to change the whole page, just the game section between 3 game pages.

Here is my directive:

```
myApp.directive('gamePanel', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "templates/wordlistPage.ejs",
    link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        attrs.ngController = "wordlistsPageController";//NOT WORKING

        scope.submitWordlist = function() {
                //change html
                elem.html('<ng-include src="\'templates/gameOptionsDialogPage.ejs\'"></ng-include>');
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
                //change controller
                attrs.ngController = "optionsPageController";///NOT WORKING
        };

        scope.backToWordlist = function() {
            elem.html('<ng-include src="\'templates/wordlistPage.ejs\'"></ng-include>');
            $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
            attrs.ngController = "wordlistsPageController";///NOT WORKING
        };
    }//end link
}
});//end directive
```

Comment: Use the `$controller` service to instantiate a controller. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not sure at all what you mean. Could you please provide an example of how to use it?

Comment: The line: 
$controller("wordlistsPageController"); 
throws a "$injector:unpr
Unknown Provider"
error.

Comment: Can you include the controller on the ejs file itself using ng-controller? Not sure if its a good idea though.

Comment: You probably got the injector error because you didn't inject scope as a local. Do that the way it is done in -- [this example](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L2336).

Comment: @NagaSandeep, I have now gotten this to work via your solution allthough it did cause some problems since the directive no longer has direct access to the controllers scope. I accessed the controllers scope through "scope.$$childTail".

georgeawg, I am still not sure what you mean.

I cant help but feel there is a better solution here. Should I be using angulars ui-router for this perhaps? I am doing my routing through node.js at the moment though and am unsure how to mix server side/client side routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to Dynamically Change a Directive Controller

To instantiate different controllers inside a directive linking function, use the `$controller` service.

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('gamePanel', function ($controller) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<p>Game Panel Template</p>",
    //controller: "pageController as vm",
    link : function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
        var locals = { $scope: scope,
                       $element: elem,
                       $attrs: attrs,
                       $transclude, transclude
                     };
        scope.vm = $controller("pageController", locals);
    }//end link
}
});
```

The above example instantiates a controller and puts it on scope as `vm`.

> ### Best practice
>
> The injected **locals** should follow the conventions of the locals provided by the `$compile` service. For more information on `$compile` service injected locals, see [AngularJS $compile service API Reference API -- controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-).
>
> ### Beware: memory leaks
>
> When destroying scopes, all watchers created on those scopes should be de-registered. This can be done by [invoking `scope.$destroy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy).
>
> When destroying controllers, all watchers created by the controller should be de-registered. This can be done by [invoking the de-register function returned by each `$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).